# How Do I Point OpenSSL to my Custom Config File?

Tags: openssl, macos-sierra

I copied `/System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf` to my home folder so I could set default values for certificate creation. How do I set up OpenSSL to use my config file instead of the regular one? I could add a statement to my ~/.bashrc file. I've done web searches and searched the openssl.org website but could not find the answer. One post on Stack Overflow mentioned a parameter -config but was not referenced in a command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would depend on what commands you're running.

If you run [`req`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Req(1)) or `ca` they would support a `-config` parameter. Which would also be visible if you run `openssl req -?` or `openssl ca -?`.

If you want to make it the actual default without exclusively specifying it you should check [Correct location of openssl.cnf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477210/correct-location-of-openssl-cnf-file).

From the above link for the options of the `req` command:

> -config filename
>
> this allows an alternative configuration file to be specified, this overrides the compile time filename or any specified in the OPENSSL_CONF environment variable.

Comment: I'm running req and using the installed Apple version of OpenSSL. So I would have to use -config myfilenameincludingfullpath in my req command? The link you provide does not include that info.

Comment: It does and it includes even more info, see the edit I'm about to make. But yes, that would be what you need to do.

Comment: Okay thanks. I did not see that req was a link in your comment.

Comment: Adding -config to my statement worked!

Comment: FYI, openssl doesn't want `-config` at the start of the parameter list. Throw it at the end of your command and it will accept it.